# Data not passed through to module inside modularized shiny tabPanel/navbarPage

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinymodules

My reproducible shiny app creates some data which shall be plotted by calling a plot module using `lapply`. It, therefore, contains the main app, the modularized `Page_ui`/`Page_server`, and the `Module_ui`/`Module_server`.

It works as a stand-alone app when it is not implemented in the `tabPanel`/`navbarPage`. In the latter setting, however, the data is created (which can be observed by the `message` output of the code) but not passed through the plot module. Why?

The parts in detail:

1. The main app, a `navbarPage` called from `ui` and `server`.
2. The modularized page (`tabPanel`) for the `navbarPage` (`Page_ui` and `Page_server`) which creates some Data (`DataPack`, a list with three elements) by clicking the "Load" button and calls the plot module via `lapply` (inspired by the example from [Thomas Roh](https://roh.engineering/post/shiny-add-removing-modules-dynamically/)).
3. The plot module (`Module_ui` and `Module_server`) for plotting each list element of `DataPack` with some statistics created inside the plot module (`AnalysedPack`).

The code does not work when wrapped in a `navbarPage`:

```
library(shiny)
library(TTR)

# Single Plot Module to be repeated using lapply in Page_server
Module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("Plot"))
}



Module_Server <- function(
  input, output, session,
  DataPack, DataSetName, InputButton_GetData) {

  AnalysedPack <- eventReactive(
    InputButtton_GetData(), {

      message(paste("Analysed Pack", DataSetName))
      AnalysedPack <- runMean(DataPack()[[DataSetName]])
      return(AnalysedPack)

    })

  output[['Plot']] <- renderUI({

      fluidRow( renderPlot({
        message(paste("Base_Plot", DataSetName))
        plot(DataPack()[[DataSetName]])
        lines(AnalysedPack(), col = "tomato", lwd = 2)}) )

    })
}






# navbarPage Module as tabPanel
Page_ui <- function(id) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tabPanel("Charts", fluidPage(
    style = "padding-top: 140px;", 
    div(id = ns("placehere")),

    absolutePanel(
      top = 0, width = "97%", fixed = TRUE,
      div(fluidRow(column(
        6, fluidRow(h4("Data Generation")),
        fluidRow(actionButton(ns("InputButton_GetData"), 
                              "Load", width = "100%"))) )) ) ))

}



Page_server <- function(input, output, session) {

  DataPack <- eventReactive(
    input$InputButton_GetData, {

      message("----- Creating new DataPack -----")
      n <- round(runif(1, min = 100, max = 500))
      message("Data length:", n)

      DataPack <- NULL
      DataPack$one   <- rnorm(n)
      DataPack$two   <- rnorm(n)^2
      DataPack$three <- sin(rnorm(n)^6)

      return(DataPack)

    })

  InputButton_GetData_rx <-
    reactive(input$InputButton_GetData)

  observeEvent(
    input$InputButton_GetData, {

      lapply(names(DataPack()), function(DataSetName) {

        id <- sprintf('Plot%s', DataSetName)
        message("DataSetName: ", DataSetName)
        message("id: ", id)
        insertUI(
          selector = "#placehere",
          where = "beforeBegin",
          ui = Module_ui(id))

        message("callModule: ", id)
        callModule(
          Module_Server, id,
          DataPack            = DataPack,
          DataSetName         = DataSetName,
          InputButton_GetData = InputButton_GetData_rx) })

    })

}






# Main App with navbarPage
ui <- navbarPage(
  "Navbar!",
  Page_ui("someid"),
  position = "fixed-bottom")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(Page_server, "someid")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code works when not wrapped in a `navbarPage` (paragraphs set in order to compare with problematic code above line by line):

```
library(shiny)
library(TTR)

# Single Plot Module to be repeated using lapply in Page_server
Module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("Plot"))
}



Module_Server <- function(
  input, output, session,
  DataPack, DataSetName, InputButton_GetData, xlim) {

  AnalysedPack <- eventReactive(c(
    InputButton_GetData()), {

      message(paste("Analysed Pack", DataSetName))
      AnalysedPack <- runMean(DataPack()[[DataSetName]])
      return(AnalysedPack)

    })

  output[['Plot']] <- renderUI({
    # `fluidRow`, `div$tag`, or `taglist` necessary as wrapper for some html object
    fluidRow( renderPlot({ 
      message(paste("Base_Plot", DataSetName))
      plot(DataPack()[[DataSetName]])
      lines(AnalysedPack(), col = "tomato", lwd = 2) }) )

  })
}






# navbarPage Module
Page_ui <- fluidPage(




  style="padding-top: 140px;",
  div(id = "placehere"),

  absolutePanel(
    top = 0, width = "97%", fixed = TRUE,
    div(fluidRow(column(
      6, fluidRow(h4("Data Generation")),
      fluidRow(actionButton("InputButton_GetData", 
                            "Load", width = "100%"))) )) ) 

)



Page_server <- function(input, output, session) {

  DataPack <- eventReactive(
    input$InputButton_GetData, {

      message("----- Creating new DataPack -----")
      n <- round(runif(1, min = 100, max = 500))
      message("Data length:", n)

      DataPack <- NULL
      DataPack$one   <- rnorm(n)
      DataPack$two   <- rnorm(n)^2
      DataPack$three <- sin(rnorm(n)^6)

      return(DataPack)

    })

  InputButton_GetData_rx <-
    reactive(input$InputButton_GetData)

  observeEvent(
    input$InputButton_GetData, {

    lapply(names(DataPack()), function(DataSetName) {

      id <- sprintf('Plot%s', DataSetName)
      message("DataSetName: ", DataSetName)
      message("id: ", id)
      insertUI(
        selector = "#placehere",
        where = "beforeBegin",
        ui = Module_ui(id))

      message("callModule: ", id)
      callModule(
        Module_Server, id,
        DataPack            = DataPack,
        DataSetName         = DataSetName,
        InputButton_GetData = InputButton_GetData_rx) })

  })

}



shinyApp(Page_ui, Page_server)
```

For completeness the code works as well when calling the module sequentially (without `lapply`):

```
library(shiny)
library(TTR)

# Single Plot Module to be repeated sequentially
Module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("Plot"))
}



Module_Server <- function(
  input, output, session,
  DataPack, DataSetName, InputButton_GetData, xlim) {

  AnalysedPack <- eventReactive(c(
    InputButton_GetData()), {

      message(paste("Analysed Pack", DataSetName))
      AnalysedPack <- runMean(DataPack()[[DataSetName]])
      return(AnalysedPack)

    })

  output$Plot <- renderPlot({

    message(paste("Base_Plot", DataSetName))
    plot(DataPack()[[DataSetName]])
    lines(AnalysedPack(), col = "tomato", lwd = 2)

  })

}






# navbarPage Module as tabPanel
Page_ui <- function(id) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tabPanel("Charts", fluidPage(
    style = "padding-top: 140px;", 

    absolutePanel(
      top = 0, width = "97%", fixed = TRUE,
      div(fluidRow(column(
        6, fluidRow(h4("Data Generation")),
        fluidRow(actionButton(ns("InputButton_GetData"), 
                              "Load", width = "100%"))) )) ),
    Module_ui(ns("Plot_1")), Module_ui(ns("Plot_2")), Module_ui(ns("Plot_3")) ))

}



Page_server <- function(input, output, session) {

  DataPack <- eventReactive(
    input$InputButton_GetData, {

      message("----- Creating new DataPack -----")
      n <- round(runif(1, min = 100, max = 500))
      message("Data length:", n)

      DataPack <- NULL
      DataPack$one   <- rnorm(n)
      DataPack$two   <- rnorm(n)^2
      DataPack$three <- sin(rnorm(n)^6)

      return(DataPack)

    })

  InputButton_GetData_rx <- 
    reactive(input$InputButton_GetData)

  callModule(Module_Server, "Plot_1",
             DataPack                = DataPack,
             DataSetName             = "one",
             InputButton_GetData     = InputButton_GetData_rx)

  callModule(Module_Server, "Plot_2",
             DataPack                = DataPack,
             DataSetName             = "two",
             InputButton_GetData     = InputButton_GetData_rx)

  callModule(Module_Server, "Plot_3",
             DataPack                = DataPack,
             DataSetName             = "three",
             InputButton_GetData     = InputButton_GetData_rx)

}






# Main App
ui <- navbarPage(
  "Navbar!",
  Page_ui("some_ns"),
  position = "fixed-bottom")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(Page_server, "some_ns")
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I found several flaws in your code: 1) the `selector` in `insertUI` is `#placehere` but you wrapped it in `ns()` in `Page_ui` therefore it can't place the new UI. Either you have to put `#someid-placehere` (since your call `Page_ui("someid")`) or remove the `ns()`. 2) You put a `renderPlot` inside `renderUI` and I don't think this works. Replace `uiOutput` with `plotOutput` and remove `renderUI`. However, it still doesn't show the plots and I guess this is due to the ids created in `insertUI`. Indeed, if you put `p("test")` in `module_ui` (in a `tagList` with `plotOutput`), ...

Comment: then "test" will be displayed three times. I also tried to put a `textOutput` in `module_ui` and `renderText` in `module_server` but it doesn't show anything. Therefore, I think the problem comes from the way modules are called in `lapply` in a module, and I don't know how to fix it. Hope this helps

Comment: The example used is a shortened version of some original code, therefore, the double entry with `renderUI` and `renderPlot`. This seems not to be the problem, however, you are right about the missing html wrapper in the form of `fluidRow`, `div$tag`, or `taglist` (I changed the code above). For completeness I will post the code which works when not wrapped in a `navbarPage` which demonstrates that the `lapply` call is fine. There must be a problem with calling the module itself or rather passing the variables to `Module_ui`/`Module_server`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code using `lapply` and the `navbarPage` doesn't generate the UI in the proper namespace, since when using the `navbarPage` construct your modules are "one level deeper". I added the updated code snippet below.

Relevant change is setting the name of your added UI component using `session$ns(id)`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(TTR)

# Single Plot Module to be repeated sequentially
Module_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("Plot"))
}


Module_Server <- function(
  input, output, session,
  DataPack, DataSetName, InputButton_GetData, xlim) {

  AnalysedPack <- eventReactive(
    InputButton_GetData(), {

      message(paste("Analysed Pack", DataSetName))
      AnalysedPack <- runMean(DataPack()[[DataSetName]])
      return(AnalysedPack)

    })

    output$Plot <- renderPlot({
      message(paste("Base_Plot", DataSetName))
      plot(DataPack()[[DataSetName]])
      lines(AnalysedPack(), col = "tomato", lwd = 2)
    })
}



# navbarPage Module as tabPanel
Page_ui <- function(id) {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tabPanel(
    "Charts", 
    fluidPage(
      style = "padding-top: 140px;", 
      div(id = "placehere"),

      absolutePanel(
        top = 0, 
        width = "97%", 
        fixed = TRUE,
        div(
          fluidRow(
            column(
              6, 
              fluidRow(h4("Data Generation")),
              fluidRow(
                actionButton(
                  ns("InputButton_GetData"),
                  "Load", 
                  width = "100%"
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
}


Page_server <- function(input, output, session) {

  DataPack <- eventReactive(
    input$InputButton_GetData, {

      message("----- Creating new DataPack -----")
      n <- round(runif(1, min = 100, max = 500))
      message("Data length:", n)

      DataPack <- NULL
      DataPack$one   <- rnorm(n)
      DataPack$two   <- rnorm(n)^2
      DataPack$three <- sin(rnorm(n)^6)

      return(DataPack)
    })

  InputButton_GetData_rx <- 
    reactive(input$InputButton_GetData)

  observeEvent(input$InputButton_GetData, {
    lapply(names(DataPack()), function(DataSetName) {
      id <- sprintf('Plot%s', DataSetName)
      message("DataSetName: ", DataSetName)
      message("id: ", id)
      insertUI(
        selector = "#placehere",
        where = "beforeBegin",
        ui = Module_ui(session$ns(id))
      )

      message("callModule: ", id)
      callModule(
        Module_Server,
        id,
        DataPack            = DataPack,
        DataSetName         = DataSetName,
        InputButton_GetData = InputButton_GetData_rx
      )
    })
  })
}



# Main App
ui <- navbarPage(
  "Navbar!",
  Page_ui("some_ns"),
  position = "fixed-bottom")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(Page_server, "some_ns")
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
#> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>